# How to correctly validate and submit if form is valid with ant design form with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I build a simple form with react, redux, typescript ant design. 
Following the ant design documentation, I created a small form using the provided  `getFieldDecorator` and `Form.create`methods. Everything works fine so far and validation is handled by ant design itself when entering data into the fields.
My main issue is with the form submit. I want to submit data only if the form is validated and the form is, therefore "valid".

The official documentation uses `validateFields` to validate the form and returns a variable which contains the errors and returns further execution so that the form doesn't get submitted.
Now with typescript I have the following signatures:
`validateFields(): void;` <- I use this method to trigger validation upon submit of the form and afterwards call `getFieldsError(names?: Array<string>): Record<string, string[] | undefined>;`

Now if you look at the example code, the ugly part is using a variable "allValid" to check if the form is valid or not. I thought there must be a simpler way of validating and submitting data if the form is valid.

```js
const UploadForm: FunctionComponent<FormComponentProps> = props => {
  const { getFieldDecorator, validateFields, getFieldsError } = props.form;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <Form
      {...formItemLayout}
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        validateFields();
        const validationErrors = getFieldsError();
        let allValid = true;
        console.log(validationErrors);
        for (let key in validationErrors) {
          console.log(validationErrors[key]);
          if (validationErrors[key] !== undefined) {
            allValid = false;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (allValid) {
          dispatch(submitFormData());
        }
      }}
    >
      <ImageComponent />
      <Form.Item label="E-mail">
        {getFieldDecorator("email", {
          rules: [
            {
              type: "email",
              message: "The input is not valid E-mail!"
            },
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please enter your E-mail!"
            }
          ]
        })(
          <Input
            prefix={<Icon type="mail" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
            placeholder="Your e-mail"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...buttonItemLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Form.create < FormComponentProps > {}(UploadForm);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/lobal_objects/Object/values) and [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the `undefined` value.

```js
validateFields();
const validationErrors = Object.values(getFieldsError());

if (!validationErrors.find(e => e === undefined)) dispatch(submitFormData());
```

Or you can disable the submit `Button`.

Validate each `Form.Item`, and allow submitting only when all validation status is `success`.

```js
<Button
  type="primary"
  htmlType="submit"
  disabled={!(validateEmptyField(name) && validateEmptyField(surName))}
>
  Submit
</Button>;
```

Use `validateStatus` to validate each `Form.Item`:

```js
function FromValidate() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [surName, setSurName] = useState('');

  return (
    <Flexbox>
      <Form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('name', name);
          console.log('surName', surName);
        }}
      >
        <Form.Item
          label="Name"
          required={true}
          validateStatus={validateEmptyField(name) ? 'success' : 'error'}
          help={!validateEmptyField(name) && 'Name cannot be empty'}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Unique Identifier"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        ...
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            disabled={
              !(validateEmptyField(name) && validateEmptyField(surName))
            }
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Form-Validate]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried the first solution and ended up with this code 
 ```const validationErrors = Object.values(getFieldsError());
   if (validationErrors.some(e => e !== undefined)) {
                    return;
                }
                dispatch(submitFormData());
            }}
        >
```

Comment: Nice, `Array.some()` is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
try {
    await form.validateFields()
    console.log(form.getFieldValue())
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Not a valid form")
}
```